# codeigniter how to restrict number of url segments in a page

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I am having a codeigniter function that does searching which is working fine but the issues arises  when I am making a new search on a single page whereby on clicking search button the same url of the single page duplicates on the url bar thus taking me to a wrong link. see how it behaves in the below snippets;

http://localhost/newsapp/bulletins/view/31

http://localhost/newsapp/bulletins/view/view/31

http://localhost/newsapp/bulletins/view/view/view/31
http://localhost/newsapp/bulletins/view/view/view/view/31

here are the functionss;

```
      public function livesearch() {

     $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
    $query = $this->news_model->get_live_items($keyword);

    foreach ($query as $row):
     echo "<li><a href='view/$row->id'>" . $row->title . "</a></li>";
    endforeach;
}
```

This one displays the search results in a another page:

```
  public function search_keyword()
 {
    $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
    $data['results'] =$this->news_model->get_live_items($keyword);
    $data["top_news"] = $this->news_model->topnews();
    $data["latest_news"] = $this->news_model->latestnews();
    $this->load->view('result_view',$data);
}
```

finally this where all the magics are happening;

```
 function view($id)
{       
    $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_one_news($id);
    $data["top_news"] = $this->news_model->topnews();
    $data["latest_news"] = $this->news_model->latestnews();
   $data['content'] = 'single'; // template part
   $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your livesearch method should be

```
    public function livesearch() {
        $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
        $query = $this->news_model->get_live_items($keyword);

        foreach ($query as $row):
            echo "<li><a href='" . base_url('bulletins/view/' . $row->id) . "'>" . $row->title . "</a></li>";
        endforeach;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try giving a full link like this

```
echo "<li><a href='".base_url()."view/$row->id'>" . $row->title . "</a></li>";
```

You are just including the `view/$row->id` so it is adding the url rather than generating the required url.